# how to use floor function in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here, my problem is how to use the `floor` function in this code because I want to upper value for display like **if value is 5.4 convert to 6 and 5.3 convert to 6**.

How to value get in upper level 0.83 to 1 in below example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="">
            <h1>Hello {{5/6}}</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"5.3 convert to 6"* - this is not a `floor` function, this is more `ceil` function

Comment: I guess its more of `Math.ceil` function

Comment: How did it get that this question is so "upvoted"?

Comment: see here in this example for php floor function work same as my requirements-<?php
echo(floor(0.60) . "<br>");
echo(floor(0.40) . "<br>");
echo(floor(5) . "<br>");
echo(floor(5.1) . "<br>");
echo(floor(-5.1) . "<br>");
echo(floor(-5.9));
?>

Comment: @axitsompura 1) We are talking about `javascript`, not `php`; 2) Do you have multiple accounts here?

Comment: No  , i know this question is for angular js but i suggest only this example

Comment: create a filter  `.filter('roundup', function () {
        return function (value) {
            return Math.ceil(value);
        };
    })` like this.

and in your html do this `<h1>Hello {{ 5/6 | roundup }}</h1>`

it will handle your view.

Answer (score -1):

Hi in this case it's better to use the Math.ceil() function which gives the ceiling value.

First u have to inject it to u're scope.U can use below code segment for that

```
$scope.Math = window.Math;
```

And then use the Math.celi() function

Answer (score -1):

try this code its definately works for you

```js
var app = angular.module('filters', []);

app.controller('currencies', function($scope){
  $scope.defaultNumber = 60.99;
  $scope.defaultNumberWhole = 59;
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #232323;
}

.credits {
  margin: 15px 0px;
}

.panel {
  margin: 15px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
      <div ng-app="filters">
        <div ng-controller="currencies">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
             <div class="panel-body">
               <h4 class="text-center">AngularJS Filter - Decimal Point Control (Angular 1.3+)</h4>
               <p><strong>Original:</strong></p>
               <p>{{defaultNumber}}</p>
               <p><strong>Currency Decimal Control:</strong></p>
               <p>{{defaultNumber | currency:'£':0}}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```